# How to stop shaky background image while resizing div

Tags: html, css

i have a div inside which there are 2 divs, out of which one is the container `image-holder` and other div has a background image to it.

what i want to achieve is that when i mouseover on the parent div, i want resize the div similar to [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqNKKN) but image is shaking while this transition. but i don't want the image shaking while resizing.

how can i achieve this without changing anything in markup?

Here is what i have tried.

```css
.first-parent {
    height: 263px;
    width:550px;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    height: 263px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #dedede;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.image-holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first-parent:hover .image-holder {
    height: 157px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.04) !important;
    transform: scale(1.04) !important;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-parent">      
    <div> 
        <div class="image-holder">
            <div class="image" style="background-image:url(https://images.steelcase.com/image/upload/c_fill,dpr_auto,q_70,h_656,w_1166/v1432747782/www.steelcase.com/Tour.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ad-description">
            <p class="owner">Sep 14 2019</p>
            <p class="description">My financial calendar test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PS: That codepen should be burninated. There's so much markup and styles errors in it... Really bad code example.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr: **Avoid when necessary, Layout Properties animation**

Instead of transition/animation - styles that affect *layout* (properties like `height`, `padding`, `border` etc...), you should rather stick to the ones that can be cheaply GPU accelerated (like `opacity`, `transform`).

- `overflow:hidden` the wrapper element, to prevent `.image` zoom out of bounds
- `transition: transform` ← instead of `all`
- Be smart, instead of animating the height of the image to a hardcoded value - which might not reveal variable description text lengths, animate instead the `height` (:D will not drastically affect performance in this specific case) of a description `:before` pseudo element that will fill it's area

```css
*{margin: 0;}

.first-parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 198px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
  background: 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
}

.first-parent:hover .image {
  transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.1);
}

.ad-description {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.ad-description:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: #0bf;
  transition: height 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1); /* here height is OK-ish - we have a solid background color */
}

.first-parent:hover .ad-description:before {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-parent">
  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F2LB.jpg)"></div>
  <div class="ad-description">
    <p class="owner">Here you can finally</p>
    <p class="description">use a variable <br>number of text lines.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS<sub>1</sub>: and sorry but I could not resist to, after fixing the CSS to perform well, to remove the unnecessary leftover `.image-holder` element.

PS<sub>2</sub>: Interesting read: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/